# How to test for the first record in a query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am writing a function that is supposed to calculate the rating of stocks based on certain business rules. The first part of the rule states that if there is a previous rating of the stock, then it will have an influence on the new rating.

UPDATE:

Since my previous description of the problem did not work, I have deleted the long winded explanation, and updated the below to show in Code what I'm trying to do.

```
Sub Test()
'Open table and get value of record above current

'Set Database Name and Import Tables
Dim curDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim tblSource As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim myCurrentValue As Double
Dim myLookingForValue As Double
Dim i

Set curDatabase = CurrentDb
Set tblSource = curDatabase.TableDefs("tblTest")
Set rs = curDatabase.OpenRecordset(tblSource.Name, dbOpenDynaset)

With rs
    i = .RecordCount
    .Move 0

    myCurrentValue = rs.Fields(1).Value

    If .CurrentRecord = 0 Then
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        rs.MovePrevious
        myLookingForValue = rs.Fields(1).Value
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set tblSource = Nothing
Set curDatabase = Nothing

End Sub
```

How can I check whether the current record is the first record?

Comment: i do not really understand what you are asking! What do you want to achieve? What "previous record" do you want to incorporate, and how, and where, previous in what way?

Comment: the table is sorted in chronological order. if the stock has previously been rated, then I need to take that into consideration.

Comment: Well, you obviously need the ISIN to query the table for previous ratings, which currently is not available within your function. - But I don't understand what exactly you are asking either!

Comment: @PhilS I tried to make things clearer... see my updates. Thanks!

Comment: @luk2302  I hope the updates clarify things for you as well. Thanks also to you for looking at it!

Comment: i would say you need a second function or sub which loops through your query and calls this function. But that's just a guess. The connex to the data and the function and the input - parameter is missing!

Comment: To clear up one misconception: If you just open a table without an explicit ORDER BY-expression, the table is in random order.

Answer (score 1):

The fact, that you are not showing, how your function is called, makes it a bit tricky to suggest an proper solution.

Anyway, you can do a SELECT COUNT(*YourTitle*).
If the count is greater than 1, you know, that there must be already one or more entries.

**[Edit]**

If you run this function while querying, you can do like i suggesteted
Just execute a query, selecting all fields you want with a Where Clause like this:

Select YourField1, YourField2 From YourTable WHERE entry_date <> YourCurrentDate.

If this query has Records, do what ever you must with them. If not, there are no existing ratings

Comment: Ok. Didn't realize that was a critical piece of info... I call the function from inside the querry using the "Formula Builder" functionality of Access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what exactly you are asking from a technical point of view.

Maybe the answer is as simple as this:
To get data from your table of previous ratings, you will need a query that retrieves the values of the last (most recent) rating in your table. That can be done with the following VBA-Code. However, as I commented before, the ISIN is required for this to work.

```
' the ISIN needs to be passed as parameter
Dim strISIN As String

Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql     As String

Dim previousPrice As Double
Dim previousFairvalue As Double
Dim previousSignal As Double

sql = "SELECT t1.entry_date, t1.entry_fairvalue, t1.Price, t1.Signal " & _
        " FROM yourTable t1" & _
        " WHERE t1.entity_ISIN = '" & strISIN & "' " & _
        " AND t1.entry_date = (SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.entity_ISIN = '" & strISIN & "' )"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Previous rating exists
    previousPrice = Nz(rs.Fields("Price").Value, 0)
    previousFairvalue = Nz(rs.Fields("entry_fairvalue").Value, 0)
    previousSignal = Nz(rs.Fields("Signal").Value, 0)
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Upvote for providing a new idea... i'm still searching for an answer, but I learned something new